# Why I can change the get-only property?

Tags: swift, get, set, protocols

Can anyone explain why I can set value to a get-only property?

Here is the example. This protocol contains get-only property of type the custom class, and a class conform to it.

```swift
protocol ViewModel {
    var title: MyTitle { get }
}

class MyTitle {
    var title: String
    var otherProperty: Int
}

class MyViewModel: ViewModel {
    var title: MyTitle
    init() {
        self.title = MyTitle.init()
    }
    func didChangeTitle(title: String) {
        self.title.title = title
    }
}
```

I think the `title` property should be get-only, and will trigger function in MyViewModel when user finish editing `UITextView`.

```swift
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {
    var viewModel: MyViewModel?
    func bind(to viewModel: MyViewModel) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if text == "\n" {
            self.viewModel?.title.title = textView.text /* Why can the property supposed to be get-only be changed here */
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

But actually I can update the value directly without the function of MyViewModel.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: You are not actually changing `self.viewModel?.title`. You are changing `self.viewModel?.title.title`. Changing a property of a class does not count as "changing the class".

Comment: Note that protocol is a requirement not a restriction. You can set MyTitle property as long as it is not declared as constant

Comment: @LeoDabus So if I don't want `title` of `MyTitle` be changed directly, I should declare it as `private` type, right?

Comment: `private` would not allow any type of access out of that class. If you would like to restrict only setting its value use `private (set)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually declaring a `get-only` property by conforming a protocol. You can use computed property, and declare it by

```
var title: String {
    return "Something"
}
```

And furthermore, you are changing a property inside a class, not that class itself

**EDIT**

Or as proposed in the comments you can define a private setter
`private (set) var title: String`

Comment: It would be much easier to declare `title` with a private set `private (set) var title: String = ""` to avoid changing it from another class

Comment: Yes I forgot about that, that's actually how to declare get-only properties